# Silverstripe Routes not accessing correct controller

Tags: php, controller, routes, silverstripe

I've built a site using Silverstripe 3.4.0 that should sort and aggregate various posts. I'm not trying to build the controller action to display these post dataobjects as a page. However, I can't seem to get the routing down to test my function to actually display a post.

The posts should belong to a TopicAggPage which has its own parent page. Thus, all post links should be structured as www.domain.org/parentpage/childpage/post/$ID

Here is the relevant code:

**routes.yml :**

```
      ---
      Name: mysiteroutes
      After: framework/routes#coreroutes
      ---
      Director:
        rules:
          '$Controller//$Action/$ID/$OtherID': '*'
```

**TopicAggPage.php :**

```
    class TopicAggPage_Controller extends Page_Controller {

        private static $allowed_actions = [
            'post',
        ];

        private static $url_handlers = [
            'post/$Slug' => 'post'
        ];
    }
```

The problem is, using a url as structured above does not direct me to the TopicAggPage_Controller. I can access the controller by using www.domain.org/TopicAggPage_Controller/post/$ID but that's not the way the urls should look for the website.

I'm confused as to why others from the Silverstripe IRC have been able to get routing to work the way I want with the same code, but mine requires the controller name. Especially because I set up the backup option of the url_handler in the controller itself. Any guidance would be appreciated.

Comment: Is that TopicAggController related to a page? Or just a plain controller without a Page / SiteTree object related in CMS?

Comment: It extends Page_Controller and is in the same php file as the TopicAggPage class. Unless there's some other way I need to relate them that I've missed, they should be related from that. I also corrected the name in my update to reflect an error I made in naming that should make sure the two are related.

Comment: Well, then the link to the action is /path-to-your-TopicAggPage/post/$ID. You can set the path/URLSegment in the CMS as it's just another page. Just add the action and the slug parameter to it. Can you paste the TopicAggPage definition (db and relations) and the dataobject of the slug?

Comment: btw: there is a nice extension for that slug stuff which might help you: https://github.com/NightJar/ssrigging-slug